# Peoplepicker list has no users to choose from to add as an Owner

Tags: 2007, people-picker

This is kind of a weird question. I have a SharePoint site and there are 3 owners on it. I want to add a brand new 4th owner, but their name is not showing up in the `peoplepicker` when I search for them. I get an error.

> "no exact match found"

despite personally adding in their email account a couple weeks ago.

Comment: can you click on the underline and see if you can get a dropdown with the correct user? Searches should be wildcard as well..

Answer (score 0):

Either the user account has not been synchronized yet or You have to click on "No exact match found" in order to view more.